# CSS/JQuery AddRemove class takes 2 clicks?

Tags: jquery, css

Live View: https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/Account/Management/PageBuilder/editor.html

If you click on the bottom row of buttons with the class name of '.Button' it'll take two clicks to add the 'ButtonActive' class.

I would also like to know how to implement it so that only one of either the 'Sub' or 'Super' script buttons can be active at a singular time.

**My Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('.Button').click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("ButtonActive") ) {
                $(this).removeClass("ButtonActive");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("ButtonActive");
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: don't bind a click event inside a click event. Also, .toggleClass will make this much easier. http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Another consideration: the sub- and super-script buttons are different than the B/I/U buttons.  You can turn on all of B/I/U but when you turn on superscript you want to turn off subscript.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
```

change to `ready`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Also, this is not passed the `eventObject` as a parameter, but the `jQuery` object itself.

Short syntax

```
jQuery(function($) {
```

And as @Kevin B mentioned, usage of `toggleClass()` would be more efficient.

Comment: I don't click on external links to any site other than jsfiddle, so you'll have to post your code.

Comment: Basically inside of the .Button there are one div with an id. if the clicked .Button's child has an ID of either 'Superscript' or 'Subscript' and one is already active, I want that one to remove for the other one. One one of either to be active at a singular time.

Comment: Give them both the same class, for example, "test". Then just do `if ($('.test').hasClass('ButtonActive')) { /* executes if either element has the class 'ButtonActive' */ }`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the logic to be able to yet do that. I have just made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e37Xw/)